# SQL query on finding emails with reports that are all ready

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, email

I have two tables `EmailQueue` and `ReportQueue`.  `EmailQueue` contains all emails that need to be sent out, and `ReportQueue` contains all reports that need to be generated.  `ReportQueue` has a column `ReportStatus` to show whether the report is ready or not. `N` being new and `C` being completed and ready.

While this is easy for me to check if all reports are ready for an email before the email is sent out inside my C# application, I was hoping to save having to pull all rows first and checking to see if reports are ready.  I was wondering if there is any way using SQL to get only the emails where all of its corresponding reports are ready or emails where there are no reports?  Thanks I'm relatively new to SQL.

If I was doing this via C# I would normally do something like

```
foreach (var email in emails)
{
    if (reports.Where(x => x.EmailQueueId == email.EmailQueueId).All(x => x.ReportStatus == "C") ||
        reports.Where(x => x.EmailQueueId == email.EmailQueueId) == null)
    {
        //Send Email out
    }
}
```

Database example structure:

```
ReportQueue
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| EmailQueueId |           ReportPath           | ReportStatus |
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|            1 | null                           | N            |
|            1 | C:\reports\report.xls          | C            |
|            3 | C:\reports\reportForThings.xls | C            |
+--------------+--------------------------------+--------------+

EmailQueue
+--------------+-------------+
| EmailQueueId | EmailStatus |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | N           |
|            2 | N           |
|            3 | N           |
+--------------+-------------+
```

In the example above, Email ID 2 and 3 are ready to be sent out but 1 is not because one of its reports are not generated yet.

EDIT: Desired result would probably be just a table of Emails that are ready to be sent so based on the above example the returned table would be

```
+--------------+-------------+
| EmailQueueId | EmailStatus |
+--------------+-------------+
|            2 | N           |
|            3 | N           |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please post the desired result (in table form).

Comment: And, yes, it can be done in SQL.

Comment: I made the changes, Theres of course more columns than what I wrote, but they dont directly relate to the query, only used when processing the email.

Comment: i think you should recheck the data you hv provided.both table having status column.also in ReportQueue there can be one and only one EmailQueueId or many.also EmailQueueId =2 is not present in ReportQueue so how come you decide if it is C.

select eq.* from EmailQueue EQ
left join ReportQueue RQ on eq.EmailQueueId =rq.EmailQueueId and eq.EmailStatus =rq.ReportStatus
where eq.EmailStatus='N'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.EmailQueueId, e.EmailStatus
FROM EmailQueue e
LEFT JOIN ReportQueue r ON e.EmailQueueId = r.EmailQueueId
GROUP BY e.EmailQueueId, e.EmailStatus
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.ReportStatus IS NOT NULL AND 
                     r.ReportStatus <> 'C' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 ;
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59903/12) Demo**.

**2nd Option**:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM EmailQueue e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ReportStatus) num, EmailQueueId 
           FROM ReportQueue
           WHERE ReportStatus <> 'C'
           GROUP BY EmailQueueId) tr
     ON e.EmailQueueId = tr.EmailQueueId
WHERE COALESCE(tr.num, 0) = 0;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59903/17) for 2nd Option

Comment: What if I want to change that to select all?

Comment: Well my EmailQueue Table has 13 columns, do I need to add them all to SELECT and Group By?

Comment: Either add them to `GROUP BY` or put each of them as argument of an aggregate function, for example `MAX`.  Another option is to restructure the query and do `GROUP BY` first and then `JOIN` the result.

Comment: Oh cool, so you have to move the Report status check into another SELECT statement inside the left join, that's interesting. Thanks for the help, I'm still grasping more complex SQL queries

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Email.*
FROM EmailQueue As Email
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmailQueueId,SUM(RStatus) As Tt
            FROM (SELECT EmailQueueId,
                CASE 
                    WHEN reportStatus = 'N' THEN 0
                    WHEN reportStatus = 'C' THEN NULL
                END  As RStatus
            FROM ReportQueue
                  ) A
        GROUP BY EmailQueueId
        ) AS Report ON(Email.EmailQueueId = Report.EmailQueueId)
WHERE Report.Tt IS  NULL
```

Comment: Wow, I can barely even begin to understand what is going on here, trying to figure out what is actually happening xD